# Get value of key from a mutable map

Tags: android, dictionary, kotlin, mutablemap

I have a `Map` which looks as follows:

```
 val myMap = mutableMapOf<String,String>() 

 myMap.put("A", "APPLE")
 myMap.put("B", "BALL")
 myMap.put("C", "CAT")
 myMap.put("D", "DOG")
 ...
```

When I print the map as follows, it prints it correctly:

```
println("MAP DATA -> $myMap")

//Output
MAP DATA -> [A = APPLE, B = BALL, C = CAT, D = DOG, ...]
```

But in my `activity` when I want to check if the `value` for a specific `key` is what it is, so that I can `check` a specific `radio button`, it doesn't work.

I tried the following:

```
 val option1 = myMap.get("A")
        
 if(option1 == "APPLE"){

    radioOption1.isChecked = true

  }
```

EDIT: The 2nd way I tried was this (in this case, the `println` text gets printed, but the radio button won't get checked.:

```
    if(myMap.getValue("A") == "APPLE"){
        println("getValue of MAP")
        radioOption1.isChecked = true
    }
```

When I try this it says : `The key 'A' does not exist in the map`.

I am struggling with it. How can I get the value of a specific key from the map so that I can check the relevant `radioButton`?

Any help or advice will be highly appreciated.

Comment: what do you get when you print `option1`?

Comment: @Stachu when I print `option1` I get `null`

Comment: @Stachu I have added another way I tried it, which does print what's in the `if` statement, but won't check the radio button (Edited my code above)

Comment: as Patrick has said, the map seems to be populated after you to get the key to check radio button, hence the null value